# Faster way to update a column in a pandas data frame based on the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with columns = [A, B, C, D, ...I, Z]. There are around ~80000 rows in the dataframe, and columns A, B, C, D, ..., I have value 0 for all these rows. Z has a value between [0, 9]. What I am trying to do is update the value of the x'th column for all rows in the data frame, where x is the current value of Z. If value of x is 0, then ignore. The data frame looks like -

```
    A    B    C    D  ...  Z
0   0    0    0    0  ...  9
1   0    0    0    0  ...  1
2   0    0    0    0  ...  2
3   0    0    0    0  ...  3
```

This is what I have so far.

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']  
for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if row['Z'] != 9:
                df.loc[index, cols[int(row['Z'])]] = 1
```

This is way too slow, and causes the script to stop executing midway. Is there a faster or better way to do it? I tried looking at np.where and np.apply, but I am not able to figure out the syntax. This is what I tried using np.apply -

```
df.iloc[what goes here?] = df['Z'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x != 9)
```

The desired output for the above sample is -

```
    A    B    C    D  ...  Z
0   0    0    0    0  ...  9
1   0    1    0    0  ...  1
2   0    0    1    0  ...  2
3   0    0    0    1  ...  3
```

Comment: Can you post a desired output for your small sample?  How can we update the xth column is x is 8 for example and there are only 5 columns?

Comment: @user3483203 I have corrected the question description and updated it with the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
cols = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'temp'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols[:-1])
df['Z'] = [9,1,2,3,1,5,4]
df = df.fillna(0)
df.update(pd.get_dummies(cols[df['Z']]))
print(df)
```

yields

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  Z
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9
1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
2  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  2
3  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  3
4  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
5  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  5
6  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  4
```

---

Pandas has a function, [pd.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), which does exactly what you want:

```
In [274]: pd.get_dummies(['A','C','B','D'])
Out[274]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  0  1
```

By making `cols` a NumPy array, you can use [NumPy integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) to generate
the desired column labels. (The purpose of the `'temp'` column is explained below):

```
In [276]: cols[df['Z']]
Out[276]: array(['temp', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'F', 'E'], dtype='<U3')
```

So that `get_dummies` generates this DataFrame:

```
In [277]: pd.get_dummies(cols[df['Z']])
Out[277]: 
   B  C  D  E  F  temp
0  0  0  0  0  0     1
1  1  0  0  0  0     0
2  0  1  0  0  0     0
3  0  0  1  0  0     0
4  1  0  0  0  0     0
5  0  0  0  0  1     0
6  0  0  0  1  0     0
```

`df.update(other)` copies non-NaN values from the `other` DataFrame into `df`. Since `df` does not have a column labeled `temp`, the values in that column are ignored.

---

Alternatively, construct `df` [by concatenating](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) `df['Z']` with `pd.get_dummies(cols[df['Z']])`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
cols = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'temp'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Z':[9,1,2,3,1,5,4]})

df = pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(cols[df['Z']]), df['Z']], axis=1)
df = df.drop('temp', axis=1)
print(df)
```

yields

```
   B  C  D  E  F  Z
0  0  0  0  0  0  9
1  1  0  0  0  0  1
2  0  1  0  0  0  2
3  0  0  1  0  0  3
4  1  0  0  0  0  1
5  0  0  0  0  1  5
6  0  0  0  1  0  4
```

Notice that some columns may be missing if there is no value in the `Z` column which corresponds to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I need, and is amazingly fast.